# I am having urls.py patterns errors

Tags: python, django

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
 path("",views.index,name="index")
]
```

i have views.py as follows

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import ClientServiceRepresentative
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    return render(request,"ClientServicesManagement/index.html",{"representatives":ClientServiceRepresentative.objects.all()})
```

When I run the application i get following error

```
    File "C:\Users\hp\KHSystem\KHSystems\ClientServicesManagement\urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    path("",views.index,name="index")
AttributeError: module 'ClientServicesManagement.views' has no attribute 'index'
```

I have clearly defined index in views why i am having this problem

Comment: comma at termination

Answer (score 1):

I think it is just the missing Komma after the

```
 path(...),
```